# How do I get value of a instance variable from a controller method when it is called inside a partial view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to rails and I am trying to get an image url using Graph API inside a partial view using a controller method. How can I return the image url stored in an instance variable from the controller method to the place where I called it.

For example:
I have a partial "_fb_comments.erb"
and I am trying to call the controller method "fb_comments" in my "SocialMediaController" from "_fb_comments.erb" partial like this ->

```
<img src=<%= social_media_fb_comments_path(:comm_usr_id => "#{comm['from'['id']}" %> />
```

And I have my "fb_comments" controller method inside "SocialMediaController" defined like this ->

```
def fb_comments
user=User.find_by_id(session[:uid])
@comm_user=params[:comm_usr_id]
@get_url=Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.token)
@image_url=@get_url.get_picture(@comm_user)
render :text => @image_url
```

There is no view associated with this controller method. Tell me if I am missing something and how can i get this @image_url value to my `<img src= />` tag in my partial view. Please help me with the code as I am completely new to rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a controller action, you need a view helper.  You can put the method  in `application_controller` and add the line `helper_method :fb_comments' at the top of`application_controller`.

```
class ApplicationController << ActionController::Base
  helper_method :fb_comments

  def fb_comments(options)
    user=User.find_by_id(session[:uid])
    comm_user=options[:comm_usr_id]
    get_url=Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.token)
    get_url.get_picture(comm_user)
  end
```

Then call it with...

```
<img src=<%= fb_comments(comm_usr_id: "#{comm['from'['id']}" %> />
```